# System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm. The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform

Tags: algorithm, digital-signature, windows-server-2003, sha1

I have installed certification from IdenTrust to my and customer's system. However, only mine can run correctly.

My local computer: Window 8, IIS 7.5, .Net v4
Our customer's system: Windows server 2003, IIS 6, .NET v4.

Certification:
    Version: V3
    Signature algorithm:  sha1RSA
    Signature has algorithm:   sha1

Question:
    1. MSDN says the class is supported on the following OSes: Window 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows Server 2008 (R2). Is this the problem why customer's system can't run correctly ? 
    2. My customer's system is running many products so it's almost impossible to upgrade in the near future. Is there any way to work around ?

Please give me some advice. I do not have much knowledge in this area.

Here is the detail of exception.

```
2015-04-01 20:09:48,296 [5] INFO - TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Attempting to assign values from the properties file.
2015-04-01 20:09:48,296 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Calling method to retrieve private key.
2015-04-01 20:09:48,296 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Attempting to locate the private key.
2015-04-01 20:09:48,374 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Acquired private key...beginning direct authentication.
2015-04-01 20:09:48,390 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Beginning direct authentication...
2015-04-01 20:09:48,390 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Authenticator service instance created.
2015-04-01 20:09:48,390 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Calling service and requesting challenge...
2015-04-01 20:09:48,906 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Challenge received.
2015-04-01 20:09:48,906 [5] INFO - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Signing challenge...
2015-04-01 20:09:48,906 [5] ERROR - OTPAuthenticator :: directUserPKIAuth :: Failed to successfully create session.  Direct authentication failed.
The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm..ctor(CngAlgorithm algorithm, String implementation)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng..ctor()
    at TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator.directUserPKIAuth(String systemId, AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
2015-04-01 20:09:48,921 [5] FATAL - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Exception encountered when attempting to authenticate.
Failed to successfully create session.  Direct authentication failed.  The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm..ctor(CngAlgorithm algorithm, String implementation)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng..ctor()
    at TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator.directUserPKIAuth(String systemId, AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.Exceptions.ChallengeFailedException: Failed to successfully create session.  Direct authentication failed.  The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm..ctor(CngAlgorithm algorithm, String implementation)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng..ctor()
    at TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator.directUserPKIAuth(String systemId, AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
    at TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator.directUserPKIAuth(String systemId, AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
    at TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator.authenticateTwoFactorOTP(String uid, String pwd, String otp)
2015-04-01 20:09:48,921 [5] ERROR - OTPAuthenticator :: TwoFactorAuthentication.com.identrust.otp.authentication.OTPAuthenticator :: Overall result of two-factor authentication (OTP/Pwd):  FAILED.
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft introduced a new cryptography API called [CNG (Cryptography API: Next Generation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.

The software you're trying to use is making use of the .NET [SHA1Cng](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cng%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is implemented using CNG. Therefore it won't run on Windows Server 2003.

Given that [extended support ends for Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=3198) on the 14th of July 2015, it would be advisable to be planning to upgrade your OS anyway, especially if you're using it for a security-critical purpose.